# starting krfb on remote host over ssh

Tags: ssh, fedora, remote-desktop

I'm trying to install some desktop sharing application on a running Fedora 38 box to which I currently only have ssh access.
I tried to start krfb with:

```
$ export DISPLAY=0; krfb
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 0
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

Tried to reinstall which didn't fix the issue. I'm thinking that it might not be able to load Qt because I'm connecting via ssh. Anyway around this?

Comment: What display do you want krfb to share?

Comment: @Kenster the display that's projected on the machine's primary screen